# Validations conflicts in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, forgot-password

I am working on a project and I am facing a problem which I tried to solve but no progress.

All these happened when I started to implement `Forgot Password` functionality for resetting password. I have a `User Model` which has validations for `password` and `password_confirmation`. I used these for registration and are working fine.

But for this functionality I am using a new controller called `PasswordResets`. I am generating a string called `password_reset_token` for my users table. And there is `password_reset_sent_at` which records the time a user asks for a reset. The process goes like this;

> 1) The User clicks `Forgot Password`?
>
> 2) He is redirected to a page where he is asked to enter his email.
>
> 3) Controller checks if the email is present in database, if yes then ;
>   3.1) I generate a random `password_token` by using `SecureRandom` and also time when he started the request.
>   3.2) Now the save happens here for sending the mail to user. Here the problem occurs. The `password_reset_token` is not getting saved into table.

The reason behind that is I am using validations for `password` and `password _confirmation` in `User.rb`. Here the action taking place is `:update`, so on update the record is asking for `password` and `password_confirmation` to be sent along with `password_reset_token` and the time.

But I tried solving by keeping validations as `:on => :create`, now it is working well but when I use the link for resetting my validations will not work for `password` and `password_confirmation`. This is like a deadlock for me. I know this is bit confusing, I am pasting some code to understand the problem.

My `PasswordResets Controller` create action:

```
  def create
    user= User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user
      user.send_password_reset
      UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
      flash[:success] = "Email sent with password reset instructions."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Email doesn't exit."
      render 'password_resets/new'
    end
  end
```

My `User Model` (user.rb)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_secure_password

  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\Z/i


  validates_confirmation_of :password_confirmation

  validates :username, :presence => true,
                       :uniqueness => true,
                       :length => {:within => 8..25}
  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :uniqueness => true,
                    :format => EMAIL_REGEX

  validates :password, :length => {:within => 8..25}

  validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true

  def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end


  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end


end
```

The error is shown at `save!` in  `send_password_reset`. I am attaching an image.

[image]

I know the problem can be solved by using `:on=>:create` for validations as `:update` request is taking place. But when I get confirmation link in my console and use it, the validations for password and password_confirmation dont work as the action here is `:update`. This is like  a deadlock.

I am really grateful to anyone who help me out from this maze.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Skip Validations using following eg.

```
def send_password_reset
  generate_token(:password_reset_token) 
  self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
  self.save(validate: false)
  UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
end
```